# Several ListDensityPlots with the same limits of ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, color, legending

I have to sample and plot three functions: $f(x,y)=cos(\pi x /2)$, $g(x,y)=2-x^2$ and $r(x,y)=3x$ in the range `x` and `y` in `[-1;1]`.

I want to make their density plots with a single `ColorFunction` to be applied to all: $0<=f(x,y)<=1$, $1<=g(x,y)<=2$, $-3<=r(x,y)<=3$.

All three density plots should be displayed with `BarLegend` scaled to `[-1,1]` with natural clipping. I have tried to do this in the following way:

```
F = Table[Cos[k*(Pi/2)], {j, -1.0, 1.0, 0.01}, {k, -1.0, 1.0, 0.01}];
G = Table[2 - k*k, {j, -1.0, 1.0, 0.01}, {k, -1.0, 1.0, 0.01}];
R = Table[3.0*k, {j, -1.0, 1.0, 0.01}, {k, -1.0, 1.0, 0.01}];

ListDensityPlot[F, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {-1, 1}}], After], 
 FrameLabel -> {{"x", None}, {"y", None}}, ClippingStyle -> Automatic]

ListDensityPlot[G, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {-1, 1}}], After], 
 FrameLabel -> {{"x", None}, {"y", None}}, ClippingStyle -> Automatic]

ListDensityPlot[R, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {-1, 1}}], After], 
 FrameLabel -> {{"x", None}, {"y", None}}, ClippingStyle -> Automatic]
```

But this affects only legend bars and does not affect the color functions of plots. How can I reach the result I need?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please do not forget to accept one of the answers by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. If you find an answer useful, you can upvote it. This is the preferred way of saying `Thanks` on stack sites. You can take the site tour by clicking on the ribbon icons  at the top-right of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

F = Table[Cos[k*(Pi/2)], {j, -1., 1., 0.01}, {k, -1.0, 1.0, 0.01}];
G = Table[2 - k*k, {j, -1.0, 1.0, 0.01}, {k, -1.0, 1.0, 0.01}];
R = Table[3.0*k, {j, -1.0, 1.0, 0.01}, {k, -1.0, 1.0, 0.01}];

{min, max} = {-3, 3};
```

If they are all on the same scale, the common scale would be `{-3, 3}`. In this case, two of the plots would have reduced range.

```
Legended[Row[
  ListDensityPlot[ToExpression@#, 
     ColorFunction -> (ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"]
         [1 - (max - #)/(max - min)] &),
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
     FrameLabel -> {{"x", None}, {"y", None}},
     PlotLabel -> #,
     ImageSize -> Small] & /@
   {"F", "G", "R"}],
 Placed[
  BarLegend[{"BlueGreenYellow", {min, max}},
   LegendLayout -> "Row"],
  Below]]
```

[image]

If the intent is to clip the function values to `{-1, 1}`, then use the function [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html) rather than the [`ClippingStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClippingStyle.html) option. However, `G` is then just `1`

**EDIT:** Corrected [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) and  [`ColorFunctionScaling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html)

```
Legended[
 Row[
  ListDensityPlot[
     Clip[ToExpression@#],
     ColorFunction -> 
      (ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][(# + 1)/2] &),
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
     FrameLabel -> {{"x", None}, {"y", None}},
     PlotLabel -> #,
     ImageSize -> Small] & /@
   {"F", "G", "R"}],
 Placed[
  BarLegend[{"BlueGreenYellow", {-1, 1}},
   LegendLayout -> "Row"],
  Below]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Its pretty close to what I needed. But I cann't understand why G is clipped at -1 instead of 1, and why F is -1 at 0 and 200 instead of being 0?

Comment: Because I didn't pay attention and forgot to correct the `ColorFunction` and turn off `ColorFunctionScaling`